# Getting codec and other info from tracksInformation on VLCKit

Tags: swift, vlc, libvlc

I am trying to get the meta information or the tracks information for remote media using TVVLCKit and MobileVLCKit but tracksinformation returns just an empty array.

Here is my code

```
import UIKit
import TVVLCKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, VLCMediaDelegate, VLCMediaPlayerDelegate {

    var mediaPlayer = VLCMediaPlayer()

    @IBOutlet weak var videoView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string : "https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_10mb.mp4")

        let media = VLCMedia(url: url!)
        mediaPlayer.media = media

        mediaPlayer.delegate = self
        mediaPlayer.drawable = self.videoView

        mediaPlayer.play()

        mediaPlayer.media.parse(withOptions: VLCMediaParsingOptions(VLCMediaParseLocal | VLCMediaFetchLocal | VLCMediaParseNetwork | VLCMediaFetchNetwork))

        print("Tracks information = \(mediaPlayer.media.tracksInformation)")
        print("Meta Dictionary = \(mediaPlayer.media.metaDictionary)")
    }


}
```

The output is

```
Tracks information = []
Meta Dictionary = [AnyHashable("title"): big_buck_bunny_720p_10mb.mp4]
```

I have compiled TVVLCKit myself, removing the no-stats from VLCLibrary.m and removing stats from the blacklist filter.

Has anyone come across this and know of a solution please?

Comment: Can you share verbose logs? Also see https://github.com/videolan/vlc-ios/blob/ae8095f15235888443b9b13bcb17fab8fd4e7e5a/Apple-TV/Playback/Playback%20Info/VLCPlaybackInfoMediaInfoTVViewController.m

Comment: Can you find the codec info of this file from the official VLC app?

Comment: Yeah, when using the official VLC app on MacOS I see the codec info.   
 https://ibb.co/W0vWB9K

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until VLC finished parsing the media. Parsing is asynchronous so the data you are looking for will not have finished to be created once you asked for it. Wait for the respective event to be triggered and fetch the information afterwards. The stats module is not related to all that. Stats are for playback only (like how many packets were processed, ..).